# How to write dictionary keys to the StreamWriter Text File

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

Run following code and see that you have text file on the desktop named `MyLogFile` including `Hello` text inside.

```
Dim Log As System.IO.StreamWriter
Log = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\MyLogFile.txt", False)
Log.WriteLine("Hello")
Log.Close()
```

How can I write Dictionary Keys into `MyLogFile`?

```
Dim MyDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
MyDictionary.Add(key:="Germany", value:="Germany")
MyDictionary.Add(key:="France", value:="France")
MyDictionary.Add(key:="Italy", value:="Italy")

Dim Log As System.IO.StreamWriter
Log = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\MyLogFile.txt", False)
Log.WriteLine(MyDictionary.Keys.ToList) 'This line need to be repaired.
Log.Close()
```

So, when I open `MyLogFile` I want to see;

Germany

France

Italy

Comment: `string.Join(Environment.NewLine, MyDictionary.Keys.ToArray())`. Does this help? Moreover, see the use of `using` statement when dealing with things such as files (and other implementing `IDisposable` interface).

Comment: Yes, please see the updated comment with code translated to vb.net.

Comment: What doesn't work? What gets printed? Do you get any error? I have tried this code on my local machine & it creates a text file with the above 3 values.

Comment: Is this the complete program? Try closing and re-opening the file or keep the file closed while its being written to.

Comment: Post the above code, I wrote this to check if things are being written to the file `Using sr As New StreamReader(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\MyLogFile.txt")
 Dim line As String
 ' Read the stream to a string and write the string to the console.
 line = sr.ReadToEnd()
 Console.WriteLine(line)
End Using`. Yes, it does write to the file. What kind of project is this? console? web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string.Join(Environment.NewLine, MyDictionary.Keys.ToArray())
```

I suppose this line helps you get what you are looking for based on my comments above.